# How to pass a SharePoint SPListItem as a parameter into a custom Web Service?

Tags: sharepoint, wsdl, asmx, webmethod, splistitem

Can you pass an SPListItem object as a parameter into a custom [WebMethod] deployed into SharePoint? I understand that it would be essentially disconnected from the the SharePoint context if it was, but that suits me fine as I'm just saving some of this SPListItem data elsewhere (no updates).

I tried this for testing purposes but SPDev threw an error generating the .disco & .wsdl;

```
[WebMethod]
public bool saveData(SPListItem ticket, string action)
{

    string msg = "";

    try
    {
        msg += ticket.Xml.ToString();
        msg += Environment.NewLine;

    }catch(Exception ex){
        msg += ex.Message.ToString();
    }
    finally{

        processLog.WriteToLog(msg, LogFile_NM);
    }

    return true;

}
```

Something about this approach seems wrong, but I can't quite put my finger on it...

Thanks.

Comment: First off, there is an awesome sharepoint based stack at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ that you should use for all your sharepoint questions. And how is the variable getting passed into the function from the web service, is it a parameterized string?

Comment: The function above is a stand alone web method exposed on the Web Service, it would need the SPListItem to be provided by a SOAP call.

Comment: Alright, I'm sorry but I won't be of much help, try the community at [sharepoint.stackexchange.com](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com), they'll probably know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, a fundamental flaw - [an SPListItem is not serializable!](http://ddkonline.blogspot.com/2009/06/sharepoint-2007-workflow-workflow.html)